Twenty Twenty One update changes dom classes and breaks my child theme
I built my first child theme and am paying the price of my ignorance.
It basically breaks all the time.  Every update to the main theme (Twenty Twenty One) seems to change some class name that my js relies on to do its business.
I had previously solved this by turning off all updates but then the site got hacked to hell.  Wordfence fixed it and said the lack of updates was causing the issue.
Am I just screwed?  Will this website break every few months?

Can you give an example? It looks like 1) broadly it's one release of old themes per WordPress version, so not too often; 2) I don't see any significant CSS changes at first glance, except wp-block-navigation was removed because it's now provided by core instead.

Broadly no I'd expect old themes to only get updates for compatibility and fixes, and no significant changes to the UI structure.

example:  an update changed a div i target from ".entry-content" to ".content-area"

Hmm, the only content-area I can see in the theme is this one at the bottom of header.php and that hasn't changed for four years. It was like that with the theme's official release in WP 5.6.

I'm not saying nothing's changed, and It's possible that the implementation of some of the editor generated stuff has changed too. But I'm surprised you're actually having problems like this. I certainly don't expect the website will break for you every few months.

whoa that's . . . really weird.  i wonder if i somehow started myself off with an ancient version of the theme by accident??
i saw somewhere that changing the content in the comments of style.css (like deleting "Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentyone") will stop it from updating with the parent theme, is that true?  makes no sense to me but if it works i'd love it.

@milpool disabling updates to a third-party theme, even a wordpress core theme, would defeat the point of making a child theme at all. The updates happen primarily to fix bugs or address security issues. If you don't care about those, just rename the theme and don't bother with a child theme at all (not recommended, though).

right, i basically should not have made it a child theme.  but i did rename it and that didn't actually detach it which is part of what has me confused
